# Debug Assertion Failed. Expression (stream !=NULL)

Tags: c, windows, events, networking, error-handling

I am getting the following error:

> Debug Assertion Failed. Expression (stream !=NULL) File:
>   f:\dd\vctools/crty_bld/self_x86\crt\src\fwrite.c

and CPU Usage 100% when 4 threads are created. The Code works fine initially for sometime and then gives this error.

The code is a UDP single Server/multiple Client application using WSAWaitforMultipleEvents().

**EDIT:**

Debugger triggers a breakpoint in fwrite.c

> ```
>   if(size ==0 || count == 0)
>         return 0;
>
>     // just checking for stream != NULL here
>     // rest of the validation is in _fwrite_nolock()
>     **_VALIDATE_RETURN( (stream != NULL) ,EINVAL, 0);** /*Debugger triggered a break point here*/
>
>     _lock_str(stream);
> ```

All the files are in one single folder which are openend using fopen(). When only two files are opened, it works fine but for more than two files, error occurs.

The code is too long so I don't know which part should I share :(

Actually there are 3 ReceiveThreads and each Receive Thread ahas its own sendThread.

Receive Thread only keeps on receiving a buffer and keep writing to a text file. If EOF or EXIT is received, the receivethread should terminate itself and its SendThread as well.

Send Thread on the other hand onlly keeps on reading from text file and keeps sending at socket.

```
DWORD WINAPI sendAllThreadProcedure(LPVOID param)
{
   threadDetailStruct* myDetailStruct =  (threadDetailStruct*) (param);
   int threadNumber,portNumber;
   char *ipNumber;
   SOCKADDR_IN sendSocket = myDetailStruct->cliSock; 
   SOCKET sendSocketIdentifier = myDetailStruct->cliSockIdentifier;
   threadNumber = myDetailStruct->threadNum;


   char clientPort[32],*clientIP = inet_ntoa(sendSocket.sin_addr);
   int cliPort = ntohs(sendSocket.sin_port);
   itoa(cliPort,clientPort,10);
//=======================================================================
   int clientSocketLength = sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN);
   char receiveBuffer[10000];
   int recv_len=0;
//=======================================================================


   char file[32]="File.txt";
   int sendCount=0;
   FILE *fpSend;
    while(1)
    {
    if(WaitForSingleObject(terminate_thread_event[threadNumber],0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
       {
          ResetEvent(terminate_thread_event[threadNumber]);
          break;
       }
    if((fpSend = fopen(TEXT(fileName), "r+b")) == NULL)
    {
       //"Unable to open the File"
       continue;
    }
   else
   {
    char file_buffer[10000];
    int bytes_read=0;
    char new_buffer[1000] = "FILE",send[1000];
    if(sendto(sendSocketIdentifier, new_buffer, sizeof(new_buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &sendSocket, sizeof(sendSocket))<0)
    {
     //FILE MEssage NOT SENNT!"
     continue;
    }
     else
     {
      while(fpSend!=NULL)
      {
       if(WaitForSingleObject(terminate_thread_event[threadNumber],0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
       {
        ResetEvent(terminate_thread_event[threadNumber]);
            closesocket(sendSocketIdentifier);
        fclose(fpSend);
        return 0;
       }
       if((bytes_read=fread(file_buffer, sizeof(char), 5, fpSend))<=0)
       {
        if(feof(fpSend))
        {
           char new_buffer[1000] = "EOF",send[1000],exit_message[12];
               if(sendto(sendSocketIdentifier, new_buffer, sizeof(new_buffer), 0,  (struct sockaddr *) &sendSocket, sizeof(sendSocket))<0)
           {
                 //"EOF NOT SENNT!"
                 break;
           }
               fclose(fpSend);
               break;
        }
        else
        {
           /*Unable to copy file into buffer*/
                fclose(fpSend);
            break;
        }
       }
      else
      {
        if(sendto(sendSocketIdentifier, file_buffer, bytes_read, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &sendSocket, sizeof(sendSocket))<0)
        {
             //"Bytes read from File NOT SENT!"
             fclose(fpSend);
         break;
        }
        else
        {
           sendCount = sendCount+1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
Sleep(100);
   closesocket(sendSocketIdentifier);
   return 0;
}

// ====================
// RECEIVE Thread
DWORD WINAPI newrecvThreadProcedure(LPVOID param)
{
   newRecvThreadDetailStruct* myDetailStruct =  (newRecvThreadDetailStruct*) (param);
char newDetail[256], threadNumber_char[12], ipNumber[32],
*detail = myDetailStruct>newsocketDetail;
   int portNumber,threadNumber_int = myDetailStruct->threadNum; 
   sscanf(detail,"%s %d",ipNumber,&portNumber);
   itoa(threadNumber_int,threadNumber_char,10);

   strcpy(newDetail,threadNumber_char);
   strcat(newDetail," ");
   strcat(newDetail,detail);
   struct node *cur, *newNode;

   EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
   cur =cread();
   cur->data = newDetail;
   cur->n=NULL;
   push(cur);
   newNode = pop();
   MessageBox( NULL,"PUSH DONE!","PUSH!",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
   if  (ResetEvent(data_available_event) == 0) // signal sender thread that data is available
      {
          MessageBox( NULL,"RESET Event is not Set","Failed!",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
      }
   LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);

   char file[64] = client.txt;

   //====================================================================
   // Creating New Socket Now
      WSADATA wsa; 

   //Initialise winsock//
   if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
      {
         char err[128];
         itoa(WSAGetLastError(),err,10);
         MessageBox( NULL,
                     err,
                     "WinSock Initialization FAILED",
                     MB_ICONINFORMATION);
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

   //Create a socket//
   SOCKET newSocketIdentifier;
   SOCKADDR_IN newSocket;
   if((newSocketIdentifier = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
      { 
        // "Socket Creation Failed",
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
   //Socket Created//

   //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure//
   newSocket.sin_family = AF_INET;
   newSocket.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
   newSocket.sin_port = htons(portNumber);

   //Bind//
   if( bind(newSocketIdentifier ,(struct sockaddr *)&newSocket, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
      { 
                     //"BIND FAILED inside Thread"
      }

   //Bind Done//

   int waitRet;
   WSAEVENT hEvent = WSACreateEvent();
   WSANETWORKEVENTS events;
   WSAEventSelect(newSocketIdentifier, hEvent, FD_READ | FD_WRITE);

   SOCKADDR_IN clientSocket;
   int clientSocketLength = sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN);
   char receiveBuffer[3000]={0};
   int recv_len = 0,receiveCount = 0;

   while(1)
      {
         waitRet = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(1, &hEvent, FALSE, INFINITE, FALSE);
         //WSAResetEvent(hEvent);
         if(WSAEnumNetworkEvents(newSocketIdentifier,hEvent,&events) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                         //"FAILURE"

               continue;
        }
         else
        {  //else event occurred starts
           if(events.lNetworkEvents & FD_READ)
               {
                 if((recv_len = recvfrom(newSocketIdentifier, receiveBuffer, sizeof(receiveBuffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientSocket, &clientSocketLength)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                        {
                           continue;
                        }
                     else
                        {
                           if(memcmp(receiveBuffer,"NewSocket",9) == 0)
                              {
                                 if(sendto(newSocketIdentifier, "NewSocket ACK", sizeof("NewSocket ACK"), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientSocket, sizeof(clientSocket))<0)
                                    {
//"NewSocket ACK not SENNT!",err,MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
                                       continue;
                            }
                         else
                            {
                                    break;
                            }
                     }
                }
            }
        }
      }
   threadDetailStruct threadDetail;
   threadDetail.cliSock = clientSocket;
   threadDetail.cliSockIdentifier = newSocketIdentifier;
   threadDetail.threadNum = threadNumber_int;
   AHN_glb_sendAllThreadHandle[threadNumber_int] = CreateThread( NULL,
                                                          0,
                                                          sendAllThreadProcedure,
                                                          (LPVOID)&threadDetail,
                                                          0,
                                                          &idThread[threadNumber_int]
                                                        );
   while(1)
      {
         waitRet = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(1, &hEvent, FALSE, INFINITE, FALSE);
         //WSAResetEvent(hEvent);
         if(WSAEnumNetworkEvents(newSocketIdentifier,hEvent,&events) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                          // "FAILURE"
               continue;
        }
        else
        {  //else event occurred starts
           if(events.lNetworkEvents & FD_READ)
             {  //check for network event starts
                     //FD_READ
                     if((recv_len = recvfrom(newSocketIdentifier, receiveBuffer, sizeof(receiveBuffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientSocket, &clientSocketLength)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                        {
//"after FD READ Could not Receive Data"

                            continue;
                    }

                if(memcmp(receiveBuffer,"EXIT",4) == 0)
                    {
                               SetEvent(terminate_thread_event[threadNumber_int]);
                    }
                if(memcmp(receiveBuffer,"FILE",4) == 0)
                    {
                     FILE *fprecv = fopen(TEXT(file),"wb");
                    while(1)
                    {
                        waitRet = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(1, &hEvent, FALSE, 0, FALSE);
                              if(WSAEnumNetworkEvents(newSocketIdentifier,hEvent,&events) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                        {
                                          fclose(fprecv);
                                          break;
                        }
                        else
                        { 
                                          if(events.lNetworkEvents & FD_READ)//else event occurred starts
                          {
                                                if((recv_len = recvfrom(newSocketIdentifier, receiveBuffer, sizeof(receiveBuffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientSocket, &clientSocketLength)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                                                      {                                   MessageBox( NULL,"error","Data Reception Failed",MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                                                      fclose(fprecv);
                                                      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                                                      break;
                                      }
                                                receiveCount = recv_len+receiveCount;
                                    if(memcmp(receiveBuffer,"EXIT",4) == 0)
                                    {
                                    SetEvent(terminate_thread_event[threadNumber_int]);
                                    fclose(fprecv);
                                    return 0;
                                    }
                                                if(memcmp(receiveBuffer,"EOF",3) == 0)
                                                   {
                                                      fclose(fprecv);
                                                      break;
                                                   }
                                                if(memcmp(receiveBuffer,"FILE",4) == 0)
                                                   {
                                                      fclose(fprecv);
                                                      remove(TEXT(file));
                                                      fprecv = fopen(TEXT(file),"wb");
                                                      continue;
                                                   }
                                                **if(fwrite(receiveBuffer, 1, recv_len, fprecv)<0)
                                                   {
                                                      MessageBox( NULL,"problem while writing file","Error!",MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                                                      fclose(fprecv);
                                                      break;
                                                   }**
                                             } //if FD_READ 
                                       }// else network event receievd ENDS
                                 }// While(1) for receiveing File Ends
                                          FILE *fp1 ;
                                          if((fp1 = fopen(TEXT(file), "rb")) == NULL)
                                             {
                                                MessageBox( NULL,"Unable to open the File","Error!",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION |MB_OK);
                                                break;
                                             }
                                          char filecmp[1000];
                                          strcpy(filecmp,"Client");
                                          strcat(filecmp,threadNumber_char);
                                          strcat(filecmp,"Original");
                                          strcat(filecmp,".txt");
                                          FILE *fp2 ;
                                          if((fp2 = fopen(TEXT(filecmp), "rb")) == NULL)
                                             {
                                                 MessageBox( NULL,"Unable to open the Original File","Error!",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
                                                 break;
                                             }
                                          int ch1  =  getc( fp1 ) ;
                                          int ch2  =  getc( fp2 ) ;
                                          while( (ch1!=EOF) && (ch2!=EOF) && (ch1 == ch2))
                                             {
                                                ch1 = getc(fp1);
                                                ch2 = getc(fp2) ;
                                             }
                                          char display[3000];
                                          strcpy(display,file);
                                          strcat(display," Received and ");
                                          strcat(display,filecmp);
                                          int idx=GetWindowTextLength(AHN_glb_resultWindowHandle);
                                          SendMessage(AHN_glb_resultWindowHandle,EM_SETSEL,idx,idx);
                                          SendMessage(AHN_glb_resultWindowHandle,EM_REPLACESEL,0,(LPARAM)"\r\n");
                                          if (ch1 !=  ch2)
                                             {
                                                SendMessage(AHN_glb_resultWindowHandle,EM_REPLACESEL,0,(LPARAM)"\r\n");
                                                SendMessage(AHN_glb_resultWindowHandle,EM_REPLACESEL,0,(LPARAM)" ");
                                                SendMessage(AHN_glb_resultWindowHandle,EM_REPLACESEL,0,(LPARAM)TEXT(display));
                                                SendMessage(AHN_glb_resultWindowHandle,EM_REPLACESEL,0,(LPARAM)" are Not Identical");
                                             }
                                          else if (ch1 == ch2)
                                             {
                                                 SendMessage(AHN_glb_resultWindowHandle,EM_REPLACESEL,0,(LPARAM)"\r\n");
                                                 SendMessage(AHN_glb_resultWindowHandle,EM_REPLACESEL,0,(LPARAM)" ");
                                                 SendMessage(AHN_glb_resultWindowHandle,EM_REPLACESEL,0,(LPARAM)TEXT(display));
                                                 SendMessage(AHN_glb_resultWindowHandle,EM_REPLACESEL,0,(LPARAM)" are Identical");
                                             }

fclose ( fp1 );
fclose ( fp2 );

                            } //if memecmp == FILE ENDS
                } //if FD_READ ENDS
            }// else if event occurred ENDS
    }//while(1) ENDS
   return 0;
}
// ===============================================================================================================
```

Comment: This assertion failure indicates that you are trying to read text from a file pointer which is NULL. Usually, a file pointer is NULL because fopen returned NULL when it failed to open the file. Check the file exists and the path is correct.You need to check that fopen() returned a non-NULL pointer. It will return NULL if the file can not be opened (such as the file does not exist when opening for read or you don't have permissions to open for write).

Comment: Why don't you run it in a debugger and share the part of the code where the crash is?

Comment: @Dayalrai : I have checks for fopen() if it fails in my code. But fopen() is successful in my case :(

Comment: @xaxxon : Added the output of debugger in Edit. Please have a look if you can help me :(

Comment: which line in YOUR code is starting the call stack to fwrite.c?

Comment: I thought it was because all of the three threads were trying to SendMessage to a single window simultaneoulsy. Removed the SendMessafge part. Got rid of Debug Assertion i guess but still CPU Usage is 100%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check

```
FILE *fprecv = fopen(TEXT(file),"wb");
```

to make sure it didn't return an error.  Also, **please** fix your indentation.  The logic is very hard to follow.

Comment: Oh yes, I know it is so complicated. Actually there are 3 ReceiveThreads and each Receive Thread ahas its own sendThread. 
Receive Thread only keeps on receiving a buffer and keep writing to a text file. If EOF or EXIT is received, the receivethread should terminate itself and its SendThread as well. Send Thread on the other hand onlly keeps on reading from text file and keeps sending at socket.

Comment: Hey, I checked for fopen(). It opens the file as far as two threads are running but as soon as third thread is started, fopen fails to open files even for previously running threads.

Comment: Well, I don't know why that happens, but at least now you know why it's crashing!

Comment: If you're running this with multiple threads, it's likely you are trying to open the file for both reading and writing at the same time.    When it fails, what is the value of errno?  See here for the listing of failures: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html  Also, can I have an upvote?  I'm 10 rep short of 3000 and I've been trying for a while :)

Comment: Thanks!  Now to play with my new powers :)