# Cannot write an array in a Ubuntu device using C++ (Debug Assertion Failed. Expression (stream !=NULL))

Tags: c++, linux, windows, visual-studio, ubuntu

I am working on Windows and I am trying to write an array into a Ubuntu device using C++ in Visual Studio 2019. Here's a sample of my code:

```
int Run_WriteCalibTable(char *pcIPAddress, int iNumArgs, float *fArgs, int *iAnsSize, char *sAns)

    ...
    ...
    ...

    char pcFolderName[256];
    char pcFileName[256];
    sprintf(pcFolderName, "%s\\%s",pcSavePath, pcUUTSerialNumber);
    sprintf(pcFileName, "%s\\calib_rfclock.conf",pcFolderName);

    // WRITE TABLE ON PC
    FILE *pFileW;
    pFileW = fopen(pcFileName,"wb");
    fwrite(&CalibTable, sizeof(char), CalibTable.hdr.v1.u32Len, pFileW);
    fclose(pFileW);

}
return 0;
```

However, I keep having this pop-up from Microsoft Visual C++ Debug Library that says:

> Debug Assertion Failed:
>
> Program:...
>
> File: f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\sefl_x86\crt\src\fwrite.c
>
> Line: 77
>
> Expression: (stream != NULL)
>
> ...

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037458/debug-assertion-failed-expression-stream-null) and I tried logging in as *root* on my Ubuntu device. I also tried:

```
mount -o remount,rw /path/to/parent/directory
chmod 777 /path/to/parent/directory
```

And I can also create/edit manualy any file in the directory I'm trying to write into with my code, but I get the same error when running it.

Anyone knows what could cause this? I think it could be on the Windows side, but I don't know what I am doing wrong. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What are the contents of `pcFileName` when you pass it to `fopen`

Comment: You never check if `pFileW = fopen(pcFileName,"wb");` suceeds. Do that and check the error. It should tell you why it fails (if it does).

Comment: I expect that the open failed and you continued trying to write anyways.

Comment: Your use of  \\ looks suspicious for linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never check that opening the file succeeds - and it most likely fails, which is why you get the debug pop-up. Your use of `\` as directory delimiters may be the only reason why it fails, but you should check to be sure.

I suggest that you use [`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) (C++17) to build your paths. That makes it easy to create paths in a portable way. You could also make use of a C++ standard [`std::ofstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) to create the file. That way you don't need to close it afterwards. It closes automatically when it goes out of scope.

Example:

```cpp
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>

int Run_WriteCalibTable(char *pcIPAddress, int iNumArgs, float *fArgs,
                        int *iAnsSize, char *sAns) 
{
    ...

    // Build std::filesystem::paths:
    auto pcFolderName = std::filesystem::path(pcSavePath) / pcUUTSerialNumber;
    auto pcFileName = pcFolderName / "calib_rfclock.conf";

    // only try to write to the file if opening the file succeeds:
    if(std::ofstream pFileW(pcFileName, std::ios::binary); pFileW) {
        // Successfully opened the file, now write to it:
        pFileW.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&CalibTable),
                     CalibTable.hdr.v1.u32Len);
    } else {
        // Opening the file failed, print the reason:
        std::cerr << pcFileName << ": " << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    }

    ...
}
```